# Hide other location on google map

Tags: api, dictionary, location, hide

How can i hide other hotel location on google map, i want to show only hotel location in my project. I tried it by many different way like visibility : off and so on... But its hide my hotel location as well. Please help to rectify this issue. i think i missed something. And what is the role of API key here?

```
<script>
function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat:-0.0044766 , lng: 51.5374279}, 
   zoom: 16,
   styles: [
   {
      featureType: 'poi',
      elementType: 'business',
      stylers: [{visibility :'Off'}]
   },
   ]
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can get the details about your hotel using [Place details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details).

Like this example:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8667904, lng: 151.1957624},
    zoom: 18,
    styles: 
      [{
        "featureType": "poi.business",
        "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]
      }]
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails({
    placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
  }, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      alert(place.name+' '+ place.formatted_address);

    }
  });
}
```

Based on [Styled Map Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/), after hiding your hotel, all that kind of buildings will be hidden too.